# Are the AND-OR and OR-AND forms of combinations exactly sum-of-products and product-of-sums?

Tags: digital-logic, design

Are "the AND-OR forms of combinations" and "sum-of-products"  exactly the same?

Are "the OR-AND forms of combinations" and "product-of-sums"  exactly the same?

In "the AND-OR and OR-AND forms of combinations", is single NOT gate  applied only to literals?

In "sum-of-products and product-of-sums", is single NOT gate applied only to literals?

Thanks.

---

The terminology comes from Mano's *Digital Design*:

**The sum-of-products and product-of-sums** are mentioned in *Section 2.6    Canonical and Standard Forms* in *Chapter 2    Boolean Algebra and Logic Gates*,

[image]

and are simplified   in *Section 3.2    The Karnaugh Map Method*   and  in *Section 3.4    Product-of-Sums Simplification*.

**The AND-OR and OR-AND forms of combinations** are mentioned in *Section 3.7  Other Two-Level Implementations* in *Chapter 3    Gate-Level Minimization*.

> The types of gates most often found in integrated circuits are NAND and NOR gates.
> For this reason, NAND and NOR logic implementations are the most important from
> a practical point of view. Some (but not all) NAND or NOR gates allow the possibility
> of a wire connection between the outputs of two gates to provide a specific logic func-
> tion. This type of logic is called  wired logic.

and

> [image]

Comment: Invert terms.  Change operators.  And they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of products and product of sums are two ways to write the expression for a combinatorial logic function using symbols, as in the example, "\$F_1 = y' + xy + x'yz'\$".

AND-OR and OR-AND are two ways to connect physical gates to implement a logical function.

There is a close relationship between them, but one is about expressing logic with symbols and the other is about building actual circuits to implement the logic.